# Import XML Data thru MSFlexigrid to SQL Table using vb6

Tags: vb6

My VB6 code reads XML file
loads into MSFLEXIGRID
loops through each record, if I see a break point, 
does not add data in sql table except one record why it is happening does not know. does not throw any error.

I'm appending my code below:

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
    Dim rsMtrData As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim irow As Integer
    rsClose rsMtrData
    rsMtrData.Open "select * from Master_Meter_Reading ", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic
    With MSFlexGrid1
        rsMtrData.AddNew
        For irow = 0 To .Rows - 1
            .Row = irow
            .Col = 0
            rsMtrData!Snapshot = .text & ""
            .Col = 1
            rsMtrData!LoadSurveyDTime = Format(.text, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:SS")
            .Col = 2
            rsMtrData!LoadSurveyDateDay = g_ConvertNumber(.text)
            .Col = 3
            rsMtrData!LoadSurveyDate = Format(.text, g_DateFormat)
            .Col = 4
            rsMtrData!LoadSurveyDateParmVal = g_ConvertNumber(.text)
            .Col = 5
            rsMtrData!LoadSurveyType = .text & ""
            .Col = 6
            rsMtrData!LoadSurveyUnit = g_ConvertNumber(.text)
            .Col = 7
            rsMtrData!LoadSurveySlipValParmVal = .text & ""
            .Col = 8
            rsMtrData!LoadSurveySlipValParmValTime = g_ConvertNumber(.text)
            rsMtrData.Update
        Next irow
    End With
    MsgBox "Data Successfully Saved", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Your is even hard to read. please edit your question. we will like to help you. you can read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please see the answer of lardymonkey and if it works, accept it as answer. This is kind of currency within SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only adding one record then updating it.  At the moment the AddNew is on the outside of the loop.  If you change the code and move the AddNew inside the For..Next loop it should add more rows.

Your code would look something like this:

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
Dim rsMtrData As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim irow As Integer

rsClose rsMtrData

rsMtrData.Open "select * from Master_Meter_Reading ", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic

With MSFlexGrid1

    For irow = 0 To .Rows - 1
        rsMtrData.AddNew    'This is the line that has moved from outside to inside the loop.

        .Row = irow

        .Col = 0
        rsMtrData!Snapshot = .text & ""

        .Col = 1
        rsMtrData!LoadSurveyDTime = Format(.text, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:SS")

        .Col = 2
        rsMtrData!LoadSurveyDateDay = g_ConvertNumber(.text)

        .Col = 3
        rsMtrData!LoadSurveyDate = Format(.text, g_DateFormat)

        .Col = 4
        rsMtrData!LoadSurveyDateParmVal = g_ConvertNumber(.text)

        .Col = 5
        rsMtrData!LoadSurveyType = .text & ""

        .Col = 6
        rsMtrData!LoadSurveyUnit = g_ConvertNumber(.text)

        .Col = 7
        rsMtrData!LoadSurveySlipValParmVal = .text & ""

        .Col = 8
        rsMtrData!LoadSurveySlipValParmValTime = g_ConvertNumber(.text)

        rsMtrData.Update
    Next irow
End With

MsgBox "Data Successfully Saved", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Lardymonkey :  Great help in the resolution of my problem. it worked like a charm